# Tag Wiki Approved by one person

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I just had a tag wiki edit approved here:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/62777

But only one person approved it. I thought two people were meant to approve edits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is the person who approved the edit is the one who made the tag & original excerpt. In these cases, the vote is treated like when you approve/reject an edit someone suggested to your own post. In both cases the vote is binding.